# how to make this kind of barplot, group a list transactions into 12 groups of bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a dataset.

Here are some transactions:

```
transaction = [1480000.0, 1035000.0, 1465000.0, 850000.0, 1600000.0, 941000.0, 1876000.0, 1636000.0, 300000.0, 1097000.0, 700000.0, 1350000.0, 750000.0, 1172500.0, 441000.0, 1310000.0, 1200000.0, 1176500.0, 955000.0, 890000.0, 1330000.0, 900000.0, 1090000.0, 500000.0, 1100000.0, 1315000.0, 426000.0, 1447500.0, 457000.0]
```

Take place on:

```
date = ['3/12/2016', '4/02/2016', '4/03/2017', '4/03/2017', '4/06/2016', '7/05/2016', '7/05/2016', '8/10/2016', '8/10/2016', '8/10/2016', '12/11/2016', '12/11/2016', '12/11/2016', '13/08/2016', '14/05/2016', '15/10/2016', '16/07/2016', '16/07/2016', '17/09/2016', '17/09/2016', '18/03/2017', '18/03/2017', '18/03/2017', '18/06/2016', '18/06/2016', '19/11/2016', '22/08/2016', '22/08/2016', '22/08/2016']
```

I am trying to group those transactions into 12 groups of bars, there are 2 bars represent 2016 and 2017 respectively in each group

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([transaction, date]).transpose(),
                 columns=['transaction', 'date'])
di = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
from collections import defaultdict
tem1 = defaultdict(list)
for i in di:
    tem1['year'].append(i.year)
    tem1['month'].append(i.month)
df['year'] = tem1['year']
df['month'] = tem1['month']
bar_df = df.groupby(['month','year']).count()
bar_df.plot.bar()
```

and I got this:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign back datetimes to column `date`, so possible get `year`s and `month`s by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html)
[`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html).

Then for `bar_df` use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `rename`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction':transaction , 'date':date})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#print (df)

bar_df = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.month,df['date'].dt.year]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or:

```
bar_df = pd.crosstab(df['date'].dt.month.rename('m'),df['date'].dt.year.rename('y'))
```

---

```
print (bar_df)
date  2016  2017
date            
3        1     3
4        2     2
5        1     0
6        2     0
7        4     0
8        7     0
9        2     0
10       1     0
11       1     0
12       3     0

bar_df.plot.bar()
```